# Mock Laravel Eloquent save() method

Tags: laravel, testing, eloquent, model

Imagine you have a controller or some code that looks something like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class TeamController {

    public function create(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $request->validated();

        $team = new Team(['name' => $request->get('name')]);
        if (!$team->save()) {
            // some really important logic you want to cover
            // cover by a test.
        }

        ...
    }

}
```

You cannot easily mock the Eloquent model without being a bit messy, see my answer on how to return **false** from the **save()** call.

Answer (score 5):

In your test simply call:

```php
Team::saving(fn () => false);
```

and your call to save() will now return false allowing you to cover that code flow.

Comment: This works like a charm!

Comment: how to do the same thing on DB::table('table_name')->insert()?